# Posting to a Facebook Page Wall from a Web Server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading documentation and Stack Overflow link all morning, but I'm just not understanding the correct process to authorize a web server to post to a Facebook page wall.

What I'm not clear on is why I have to post to Facebook as a Facebook User, using an access_token, meaning that this user has to log into Facebook manually to authorize my app.

I'm not trying to authorize a User, nor any of my visitors to do anything with their accounts, so I don't need any permissions from them. Instead, I'm trying to authorize my Web Server to post updates to its wall as a specific Page.

Why do I have to use a user access_token to do this? I'm not attempting to impersonate the **user**, I'm trying to post to the **page** as the **page**...

Is it possible to authorize a user and get their access token without having to create a login page on the Web Server? I don't want to have to require the user to login to make this work, I thought that was the point of having an app ID and Secret?

I guess my question is this: Is it not possible to allow a web server to post to a Facebook page wall as that page, without having to present a login dialog to a specific user? If it is possible, what is the correct workflow to set this up?

Comment: the facebook documentation says: App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted an open graph publishing permission to your application.

So how do I grant this permission? do I have to create a login page on my web server? this is not what I want, is it not possible to authorize the app through the developer portal or manually somehow without creating a custom login page?

Comment: one more question, I am both the creator of the page, and the creator of the Facebook Application, and am listed as Administrator of both. Why is this insufficient to allow the App Token to post to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to post to a Page as a Page, you have to use a Page Access Token. You get that with a User Access Token, and you can extend it so it will stay valid forever.

Steps:

- Request a User Access Token with the `manage_pages` permission (valid for up to 2 hours)
- Extend the User Access Token (valid for up to 60 days)
- Get the Extended Page Access Token for your Page with the User Session
- Store and User The Page Access Token in the publish call

It may sound a bit complicated, but there are many tutorials for this and you don´t actually need to program it, you can just use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Here are some Links about the Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ (see "Extended Page Access Token" for a step by step tutorial)

Comment: thank you for the quick and helpful reply! this makes sense except for the user access token. Which user is this? if I understand you correctly, no matter what I do, the web site application will always have to reauthenticate manually, is that correct? Would it be easier to then make a single page on the site for the web site admin to periodically "reauthorize" the server to post to the page as themselves, and THAT is the user token I should be using? how would I know to notify them that it's time to reauthorize?

Comment: the user must be an admin of the page, of course. it would be weird if you could just post to a page without ever authorizing any user.

Comment: please take a look at the links i posted. extended page access tokens are valid forever, you do not need to refresh them.

Comment: the user token is only used once, just to get a page access token. after that, you don´t need a user token anymore.

Comment: heh yea sorry the web site admin would also be a page admin of course :) so in order to get the user access token I either need to a) create a login page or b) use the Graph API explorer to create one and use that to generate the permanent one. I dont want to have to teach the end user to use b) so it makes sense to make a login page for them to authorize, yes? there is no other way to get it, correct?

Comment: no, there is no other way. you have to get a page access token either via graph api explorer (ONLY possible for an app admin), or with a user login - if you want to make it available for other users too.

Comment: but: keep in mind that you need the "manage_pages" permission either way. but if you want other users to use it, you have to go through the review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

Comment: thank you, this is probably the part I was missing to put it all together, thank you kindly for clearly lining this up for me!